Как отключить в телеграм боте предварительный просмотр ссылок в библиотеке Telegram.Bot C#
Как можно в сообщение от бота отключить предварительный просмотр ссылок ? К примеру в библиотеке aiogram3.x на Python есть параметр disableWebPagePreview, который можно выключить или включить. Так вот, какой аналог в библиотеке Telegram.Bot на C#.

https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot/blob/master/src/Telegram.Bot/Types/LinkPreviewOptions.cs

@EvgeniyZ А можете подсказать как пользоваться этим классом? Просто создать объект и там IsDisabled присвоить true ?

Я вам советую научиться пользоваться IDE, а также научиться читать чужой код) Вам ведь IDE должна говорить какой метод и что принимает, там бы увидели. что условный SendTextMessageAsync принимает ряд параметров, одним из которых является linkPreviewOptions, вот вам туда и надо передать заранее созданный объект с нужными опциями.

@EvgeniyZ Все понял, спасибо! Я создал объект var DisableLink = new LinkPreviewOptions();, далее полю IsDisabled присвоил DisableLink.IsDisabled = true; и далее в моем случае в методе  EditMessageTextAsync параметру linkPreviewOptions присвил объект DisableLink. И теперь ссылка в сообщение от бота не отображается.
